# Typescript - Partial override of types from npm package interfaces

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a typescript package where i have Types and Interfaces that uses that Types.
And i would like to make Types customizable without touching the Interfaces.
I know that can i totally override or extend a package typing with a declaration file, but in this case it would be a partial override.

In my package I have something like:
(with more props and types)

```
// @package/typings.ts

type Color = 'white' | 'black';

interface IComponent {
  color?: Color;
}
```

In a project where I use that package i have my custom Color type

```
// my-project/typings.ts

type Color = 'red' | 'blue';
```

But i can't find a way to use the package interfaces with user defined types.
The result i'm trying to reach is something like that:

```
my-component.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { IComponent } from '@package';

const Mycomponent: React.FC<IComponent> = ({color = 'red'}) => { ... }
```

Is it possible to make it work without rewriting the entire declaration file?

Comment: Generics might help you: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html.

Comment: Unfortunately, that can't be done. You can do things like augment interfaces with additional members or overload method or function declarations but you simply can't change that particular property of the interface because it's already declared by the library

Comment: Thanks @НиколайГольцев, i solved using generics!